# How to prevent Activity on looping? I think runOnUIThread might be the culprit

Tags: android, loops, android-activity

There seem to be a major looping bug in my program when I ran it (debugged in my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3)

3 ImageButton with onClickListener eventually calls the countDown() method

apparently when I press two ImageButtons (with onClickListener) or double clicked the same button before it becomes `imageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` , startActivity(Intent) goes on a wild loop chase! I didn't want to try to go trial-and-error debugging on it because my Tablet (for some reason) loses the ability to connect via USB and I had to factory reset it to be able to get the USB connection back (and that's quite a hassle).

I have 3 methods that may have cause this:

`public int setInterval()` which returns --interval (global int variable)

`public void countDown(int interval)` which contains a Timer class with

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  // Need to show TextView changes
              public void run(){
                 TextView.setText(setInterval() + 1); //changes text as if count down
                         // the .setText(setInterval); suddenly decrement too fast
                 if(win){
                     //Do something
                 }
                 else{
                     //Do something and also...
                     goToResult(); // I believe this is looping
                 }
              }
         }
    }
}); }}, delay, period);
```

`public void goToResult()` which also contains a Timer class (same object name, global)

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
         setInterval();

         if(interval < 0){
             // Do startActivity(Intent); HERE
         }

    }, delay, period);
```

Comment: Firing startActivity Intents in a repeating TimerTask doesn't sound like a good idea.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't need a repeating timer.

Comment: basically, i needed it so that after a textView.setText("You Lost") is displayed for reading, startActivity(Intent) will display the ResultActivity.class. In other words, I want to call the ResultActivity after a 3 second delay

Comment: what do you mean? i think my timer will repeat only when i press the imageButton, no?

Comment: You are mistaken, please see the documentation for TimerTask.